# Dealing with negatives in calculations (Databricks-Spark SQL)

Tags: apache-spark-sql

When multiplying two columns together in a spark SQL table with random negative values, returns "NaN" for those which have a negative in one of the columns.
Any techniques to help get the calculations work?

```sql
SELECT temperature * days FROM weather_data
```

Comment: Please can you provide the table definition for weather_data. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get `NaN` from a multiplication, mybe one or more columns contains `NaN` values. You can use [`nanvl`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#nanvl) to set a default value (ex. 0) when the column is `NaN`. Use it with [`coalesce`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#coalesce) to handle nulls too:

```sql
SELECT coalesce(nanvl(temperature, 0), 0) * days FROM weather_data
```

Example:

```scala
weather_data table:
+-----------+----+
|temperature|days|
+-----------+----+
|        NaN|   1|
|     -12.34|   2|
|       null|   3|
|       15.5|   4|
+-----------+----+

spark.sql("SELECT coalesce(nanvl(temperature, 0), 0) * days AS mul FROM weather_data").show()

+------+
|   mul|
+------+
|   0.0|
|-24.68|
|   0.0|
|  62.0|
+------+
```